# Testing for correlation between differences

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

I am trying to determine whether a group of objects ($n = 100$) are spatially ordered (on a plane) with respect to the value of a particular property $p$ (a scalar).

If I had a strong sense of which single direction this ordering might occur along, I could simply project the $x$ and $y$ positions onto this vector and correlate this projection with the property value. But I don't - and I'm not even sure if it would be a linear or even monotonic relationship.

So as a more general metric I've used correlation. First, I generated two new vectors: one which contains all of pairwise differences among the values of the $p$, and the other which contains the Euclidean distances between the pairs of objects. Then I calculate the correlation coefficient between the two vectors.

This metric seems to produce sensible results. Data sets which have (by construction) a topographic organization produce higher values of correlation than those which do not. **My question is:** what statistical test can I use to accurately determine whether the correlation value is "significant?" Or what is a more appropriate (but equally general) metric to use?

I am fairly sure that the standard p-value associated with the correlation coefficient is going to be totally invalid because the $n^*$ (length of the vectors) used to calculate $p$ is $n^2/2 - n$ (i.e. $>> n$). So I tried calculating $p$ using the actual value of $n$, instead of the inflated one, but that seems to *underestimate* the significance of a particular value of $r$, which I'm inferring from the distribution of p values on simulated null data. I wrote some code (Matlab) to illustrate:

```
N = 10;

n = 10000;

p = nan(n,1);
p2 = nan(n,1);
pCorr = nan(n,1);
pCorr2 = nan(n,1);

for i = 1:n

    x = randn(N,1);
    y = randn(N,1);

    dx = nan(N);
    dy = nan(N);

    for j = 1:N
        for k = 1:N

            if k >= i
                continue
            end

            dx(j,k) = abs(x(j) - x(k));
            dy(j,k) = abs(y(j) - y(k));

        end
    end

    [r,p(i)] = corr(dx(:),dy(:),'rows','complete');

    p2(i) = PvalPearson('b',r,N);

end
```

where `PvalPearson` is:

```
t = rho.*sqrt((n-2)./(1-rho.^2));
p = 2*tcdf(-abs(t),n-2);
```

There is obviously no relationship between x and y, and yet this procedure produces p < 0.01 26% of the time, and p2 about 0.1% of the time, instead of the expected 1%.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one route is a permutation test. Here is the code:

```
N = 10;

n = 5000;
nPerm = 100;

p = nan(n,1);

for i = 1:n

    x = randn(N,1);
    y = randn(N,1);

    rPerm = nan(nPerm,1);

    for ii = 1:nPerm

        if ii > 1
            yIdx = randperm(N);
            yPerm = y(yIdx);
        else
            yPerm = y;
        end

        dx = nan(N);
        dy = nan(N);

        for j = 1:N
            for k = 1:N

                if k >= i
                    continue
                end

                dx(j,k) = abs(x(j) - x(k));
                dy(j,k) = abs(yPerm(j) - yPerm(k));

            end
        end

        rPerm(ii) = corr(dx(:),dy(:),'rows','complete');

    end

    p(i) = sum(rPerm(2:end) > rPerm(1))/n;

end
```

Which gives a sensible distribution of p-values.